# How to setup url in JavaScript to pass multiple parameter to controller in Laravel without using request

Tags: laravel, url, parameters, controller

I setup the url by JavaScript to call a function in controller with only one parameter($RoleID)  like this

```
$(document).on('change','#role',function(){
    $RoleID = $(this).val();
    let $url = '{{route("Admin.role.permission.LoadMember",':id')}}'
    $url  =  $url.replace(':id', $RoleID);
    $.ajax({
        url:$url,
        success:function(data)
        {
            $('#member').append(data);
        }// end fucntion success
    });
});
```

It works ok, Now I would like to do the same with more than one parameter without using Request
I tried like this

```
 document.getElementById('function').addEventListener('change', function(e) {
  if (e.target.name==='function') {
    $FncID = e.target.value;
    let $url = '{{route("Admin.role.permission.LoadActionsInRolePermissions",'[$ModuleID,$RolID,$FncID]')}}';

    $.ajax({
        url:$url,
        success:function(data)
        {
            $('tbody').html(data);
            //$('#member').append(data);
        }// end fucntion success 
    });
  
  }
})
```

But unfortunately, It is not work. Pls help me.
Thank in advance

Answer (score 0):

You haven't shown us how you defined the route, nor what laravel version you're using, but I highly suggest taking a read on the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#route-parameters) on how route parameters work.

As example, say this is your `LoadMember` route:

`Route::get('permission/load-member/{id}', [PermissionController::class, 'loadMember'])->name('Admin.role.permission.LoadMember')`

Then, as follows:

`{{route("Admin.role.permission.LoadMember",['id' => ':id'])}}`.

By passing an associative array with `key => value` assignment, Laravel knows where to place the given values in the url.

For a multi-parameter route, it works exactly the same:

`Route::get('permission/load-actions-in-role-permissions/{moduleId}/{rolId}/{fncId}', [PermissionController::class, 'loadActionsInRolePermissions']) ->name('Admin.role.permission.LoadActionsInRolePermissions')`

`{{route("Admin.role.permission.LoadActionsInRolePermissions",'['moduleId' => $ModuleID, 'rolId' => $RolID, 'fncId' => $FncID]')}}`

Also, may I suggest using `camelCase` for variable names, and `kebab-case` or `snake_case` for route naming? It highly improves readability and future developers who might work on your project will have a better guess at how your route structure works.

Comment: Thank Yinci.
I setup the url as follow
 let $url = '{{route("Admin.role.permission.LoadActionsInRolePermissions",[':ModuleID',':RolID',':FncID'])}}';
    $url  =  $url.replace(':ModuleID', $ModuleID);
    $url  =  $url.replace(':RolID', $RolID);
    $url  =  $url.replace(':FncID', $FncID);
from you advice. It's work.
Thank so much